# Views sum row for Degree

Tags: views, entities

I am trying to get the SUM of a group of fields in a view. We hold events and I wanted to create a view that showed How many degree types by total. See below image for quick idea.

[image]

So, If there are 20 MD's, I want one row that shows MD's with a total of 20 - versus 20 rows of MD's.

I have look at views aggregation but since it isn't a number I can not see it working. I have also looked at view calc but that just shows a total at the bottom.

I am looking to figure out the best way to handle this. If I have to custom code any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to try using the [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) community module.

The example from the Project page (very similar to your own):

> Say the original View based on raw database results looks like below.

```
Industry    Company Name    Turnover
IT          AquiB           $25,000,000
Clothing    Cenneton        $99,000,000
Food        Heiny           $66,000,000
IT          PreviousBest    $5,000,000
Food        McRonalds       $500,000,000
```

> Then with the grouping taking place on, say Industry, and aggregation
>   functions TALLY, ENUMERATE and SUM applied on Industry, Company Name
>   and Turnover respectively, the final result with a descending sort on
>   the last column will display like below. Note that the module
>   identified three groups. It also added a totals row, Views Calc style.

```
Industry        Companies            Turnover
Food (2)        Heiny, McRonalds     $566,000,000
Clothing (1)    Cenneton             $99,000,000
IT (2)          AcquiB, PreviousBest $30,000,000
Totals              5                $695,000,000
```

At that point I think you just need to play with output settings of that module ...

Comment: Thank you. The hard part now if figuring out how to make is work on my data. Initial try it isn't outputting it the way I want yet but will keep trying. Thanks!

Comment: IS there a tutorial out there for the Views Aggregator Module?

Comment: ... this is the 2nd Google result for "views aggregator plus" http://www.wdtutorials.com/tags/views-aggregator-plus

That Youtube tutorial shows how to aggregate a columns' value, i think it's exactly the "38" total you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) module.

> This module adds simple calculations to a views table. Requires the
>   Views module.
>
> You can SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, MIN, MAX, or AVG selected columns. A plug
>   in theme makes the view look more spreadsheet-like (right justifies
>   numeric fields, shades calculated columns and rows, and underlines
>   calculated rows).

[image]

Then all you need to do is to set up aggregation properly. You should do a COUNT aggregate on a field that all of your degrees have in common, for instance content type.

Comment: Reynolds, OP tried this module. Find in OP's post -> "I have also looked at view calc but that just shows a total at the bottom"  I think you missed this point from OP's posts :)

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 (at the time of this writing), there is no [Views Summarize](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_summarize), no [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc), and [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) [didn't work for me](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294654/how-does-one-add-a-totals-row-to-views-results).

So I created another view with aggregation, and included it in the footer with
*Global: View area*.  It won't actually be a row in the table, but if you want it to look like it is, you could fix that with some theming.