# Show the count of the total results when searching with a search api solr view

Tags: search, 9

I am working on a view which uses Search API Solr.

When I search for an article, I want to see how many results Solr has found.

How can I do this in Drupal 9?

Comment: Does this help? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294654/how-does-one-add-a-totals-row-to-views-results

Comment: This did the job for me. Thank you!

Comment: I've added the same as an answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing result counts in Search API views are the same as for any Drupal View. See [How does one add a Total(s) row to Views results?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294654/how-does-one-add-a-totals-row-to-views-results) for multiple ways to do so.